# How do I balance the reaction equation of zinc and nitric acid?

Tags: redox, oxidation-state

How would you balance the following reaction using the oxidation number method?
$$\ce{Zn + HNO3 -> Zn(NO3)2 + NH4NO3 + H2O}$$

My approach:
Half reactions:
\begin{align}
\ce{Zn &-> Zn(NO3)2} & \text{Change in oxidation state of }\ce{Zn} &= 2\\
\ce{2HNO3 &-> NH4NO3}& \text{Change in oxidation state of }\ce{N} &= 8\\
\end{align}

Multiplying by the L.C.M of the change of the oxidation number.
\begin{align}
\ce{4Zn &-> 4Zn(NO3)2}\\
\ce{2HNO3 &-> NH4NO3}
\end{align}

Adding them,
$$\ce{4Zn + 2HNO3 -> 4Zn(NO3)2 + NH4NO3}$$

I don't know how to proceed further.

Am I going wrong in any of the above steps?
(Please don't convert the reactants and products to ions, and solve it using the method that I am using, so that I can identify my mistake)

Comment: Your half reactions are not balanced, that's the problem.

Comment: I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: You should convert the reactants and products to ions to identify what actually changes. And you must not not forget the electrons! $\ce{Zn -> Zn^2+ +2e-}$, etc.

Comment: But my book says when writing half reactions in oxidation number method, only the atoms whose oxidation number changes should be balanced. Well, that's what I did.

Comment: Still, try to balance the half-reactions before adding them together. I believe that's the easier way.